# Prove that $\operatorname{Spec}\sqrt2$ contains infinitely many powers of $2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\spec\sqrt2=\{\lfloor k\sqrt2\rfloor: k \ge 0\}$.

I have no idea of how I can prove the statement in the question.

> Prove that $\spec\sqrt2$ contains infinitely many powers of $2$.

Comment: The most obvious place to start would be to enumerate the first few values of $\lfloor k \cdot \sqrt{2}\rfloor$ to get a feel for how it behaves. The next most obvious is to devise an algorithm for solving $\lfloor k \cdot \sqrt{2} \rfloor = 2^n$ for $k$.

Comment: What a strange notation. Why $\mathrm{Spec} \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @Alexander: Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, refer to this sequence as the spectrum of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: As stated, this question is obviously true.  Do you mean infinitely many ***integer*** powers of 2?

Comment: @Graphth: Of course.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I want the OP to say that :)

Comment: What mean the symbol ⌊ ⌋?

Comment: @Tomás: The floor function; $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the unique integer $n$ such that $n\le x<n+1$.

Comment: @Tomás: While rewriting your question in readble $\LaTeX$, I introduced this usual symbol for the floor function (yo will find the correponding symbol for ceiling in my answer below).

Comment: I see. Thanks..

Comment: It is probably an idiotic question, but why is this more complicated to prove than proving line $y = mx+b$ contains infinitely many integer powers of two? Or to just prove the generic case that $\lfloor k\cdot a\rfloor$ would contain infinitely many integer powers of 2 for any positive real number $a$? I suppose what I mean is, why can't you just use the definition for the range of the function as your argument? The Spec function as defined seems to have a range that would include all nonnegative integers, thus infinitely many powers of 2.

Comment: @cheepychappy: I assume that $k$ is meant to refer to natural numbers only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k=\lceil 2^n\sqrt 2\rceil$. Then 
$2^n\sqrt 2<k<2^n\sqrt 2+1$.
In fact we have either $2^n\sqrt 2<k<2^n\sqrt 2+\frac12$ or $2^n\sqrt 2+\frac12<k<2^n\sqrt 2+1$, depending on the ($n+1)$st binary digit of $\sqrt 2$ (which becomes the first digit of  $2^n\sqrt 2$).
Since $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, there are infinitely many $n$ (and correspondingly infinitely many $k$) such that 
$$2^n\sqrt 2<k<2^n\sqrt 2+\frac12$$
holds. Together with  $k\sqrt 2 -1<\lfloor k\sqrt 2\rfloor <k\sqrt 2$ we find 
$$ 2^n\cdot 2-1 <\lfloor k\sqrt 2\rfloor <2^n\cdot 2+\frac{\sqrt 2}2,$$
hence $\lfloor k\sqrt 2\rfloor=2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I see a lot of unexplained things, which I don't seem to be able to comprehend :( .

(n+1)st binary digit is the one counted from the left end, right?
And, how does this **bit** influence the range of k like you posted?
Infinitely many k? But k is a natural number, right? How would k take infinitely many values in between 2 real numbers differing by 1/2?